# Why would a tuple in a data structure be nested in a list?

Tags: python

```
("horses are too tall and they pretend to care about your feelings", {
        'entities': [(0, 6, 'ANIMAL')]
    })
```

I am seeing this data structure. It is a tuple with the second element as a dictionary entry:

```
'entities': [(0,6, 'ANIMAL')]
```

My question is, why is the [] needed, instead of the simpler form:

```
   'entities': (0,6, 'ANIMAL')
```

Comment: That depends entirely on the use case.  Nothing in the code you posted requires the brackets.

Comment: `[(...)]` and `(...)` are different objects. The first is a list containing a single tuple and the second is a single tuple. Tuples and lists are different, I'd encourage you to read up on the difference

Comment: How could we possibly answer this without knowing how this is used?

Comment: @Prune, my question is, why is the author of the code complicating the issue by adding an additional bracket?

Comment: I would have a long talk with this author. They obviously are making things harder for no reason. Or you are leaving something out of context where this would be needed.

Comment: @user697911: perhaps the author intends to add more tuples to the list later? The key `entities` is plural, so more than one value may be part of the design, even if this specific literal doesn't need more than one.

Comment: @user697911 We have no idea.  Again, it depends on the use case, which you haven't provided.

Comment: @Blckknght, I think your explanation makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Comment: None of us can possibly know; it would help add context if you tell us **which code/ package/ function (/website) produced that code?** which JSON package? which Python script? But even then likely we can't know. Does that code ever produce lists with more than one tuple? (as the name 'entities' suggests it might, like @Blckknght suggested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the word `entities` being in the plural form it's apparent that the author of the data structure intends this key to be a list, most likely meant to identify certain words in the sentence as known entities, so that one can have, for example:

```
("Joe loves dogs", {
        'entities': [(0, 3, 'PERSON'), (10, 14, 'ANIMAL')]
})
```

to denote that the characters from index `0` to `3` refer to a person, and that the characters from index `10` to `14` refer to an animal.